# How to override ansible_become for a specific task?

Tags: ansible

My hosts file defines, for a given host:

```
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_become_user=my_user
ansible_become=true
```

In several tasks, I don't want to become my_user.  Setting `become: false` has no effect, while `ansible_become: false` results in "ERROR: ansible_become is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler"

Is what I am trying to do possible?  I assume that the typical pattern is to do the reverse of what I am doing here, and connect as my_user, then use `become_user: root` as needed?

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9

Comment: If you can use the version 2.0+ then you can use the block feature to use it for couple of tasks at once

Answer (score 13):

It is not always practical to rewrite everything to invert the become logic. Sometimes you do just need to override the inventory become setting for a specific task and there is a simple way to do that. Instead of setting `become` on the task, instead set the var `ansible_become` for the task:

```
- name: This will run without become
  command: whoami
  vars:
    ansible_become: false
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can remove the `ansible_become_user=my_user` and `ansible_become=true` from the hosts file.
2. As you said, you have several tasks, where you don't want to become
   a user, add `become: yes` and `become_user: <some-user>` to the tasks, where you want to become .

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- name: example play
  hosts: myhost
  tasks:
  - name: run as user in inventory
    debug: msg=$USER

  - name: run as root user
    become: true
    become_user: root
    debug: msg=$USER
```